# Find these triples such that the product of any two increased by the third one gives a square

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

Find these triples such that the product of any two increased by the third one gives a square.

(The three numbers are **not equal to each other** otherwise the result will be trivial.)

> For example, he desired three rational numbers, the product of any two of which increased by the third shall be a square.
>
> "*History Of The Theory Of Numbers Vol-II*" by Leonard Eugene Dickson
>
> Preface, p-iii
>
> https://archive.org/details/HistoryOfTheTheoryOfNumbersVolII/page/n3

\begin{align*}
\left\{
\begin{split}
xy+z&=a^2\\
xz+y&=b^2\\
yz+x&=c^2\\
xy+x+y&=d^2\\
xz+x+z&=e^2\\
yz+y+z&=f^2
\end{split}
\right.\quad(1)
\qquad\qquad\left\{
\begin{split}
xy+z&=a^2\\
xz+y&=b^2\\
yz+x&=c^2\\
xy+x+y&=d^2\ne\square\\
xz+x+z&=e^2\ne\square\\
yz+y+z&=f^2\ne\square
\end{split}
\right.\quad(2)
\end{align*}

I find that there are two situations. Here are some examples.

\begin{align*} 
\color{black}{ 
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}     
\hline  
&\begin{split}   
\boxed{\left(d,e,f\right)\in\mathbb{Q}^3}\qquad\quad\,\\ 
\,\,\left(x,y,z\right)\quad\left(a,b,c\right)\quad\left(d,e,f\right)\, 
\end{split}&     
\begin{split}   
\boxed{\left(d,e,f\right)\notin\mathbb{Q}^3}\qquad\quad\,\\   
\,\,\left(x,y,z\right)\quad\left(a,b,c\right)\quad\left(d,e,f\right)\,
\end{split}\\       
\hline   
\begin{split}   
\left(x,y,z\right)\in{\mathbb{Z}_-}\!\!^3 
\end{split}&   
\begin{split}
\\
\left(-3,-6,-14\right)\,\left(2,6,9\right)\,\left(3,5,8\right)\\
\\
\end{split}  
&   
\begin{split}
\\
\left(-5,-21,-69\right)\,\left(6,18,38\right)\,\left(\sqrt{79},\sqrt{271},3\sqrt{151}\right)\\
\\
\end{split}\\     
\hline   
\begin{split}   
\begin{split}   
\left(1,y,z\right)\in{\mathbb{Z}_+}\!\!^3 
\end{split}
\end{split}&   
\begin{split}
\\
\left(1,4,12\right)\,\left(4,4,7\right)\,\left(3,5,8\right)\\
\\
\end{split} 
&   
\begin{split}
\\
\left(1,16,33\right)\,\left(7,7,23\right)\,\left(\sqrt{33},\sqrt{67},3\sqrt{577}\right)\\
\\
\end{split} \\     
\hline   
\begin{split}   
\begin{split}   
\left(x,y,z\right)\in{\mathbb{Z}_+}\!\!^3 
\end{split}
\end{split}&   
\begin{split}
\\
\left(12,33,88\right)\,\left(22,33,54\right)\,\left(21,34,55\right)\\
\\
\end{split} 
&   
\begin{split}
\\
\left(8,17,89\right)\,\left(15,27,39\right)\,\left(\sqrt{161},\sqrt{809},\sqrt{1619}\right)\\
\\
\end{split} \\  
\hline   
\begin{split}   
\left(1,y,z\right)\quad\\
\in{\mathbb{Q}_+}\!\!^3\setminus{\mathbb{Z}_+}\!\!^3
\end{split}&   
\begin{split}
\\
\left(1,\tfrac{15}{2},\tfrac{35}{2}\right)\,\left(5,5,\tfrac{23}{2}\right)\,\left(4,6,\tfrac{25}{2}\right)\\
\\
\end{split} 
&   
\begin{split}
\\
\left(1,\tfrac{13}{5},\tfrac{32}{5}\right)\,\left(3,3,\tfrac{21}{5}\right)\,\left(\sqrt{\tfrac{31}{5}},\sqrt{\tfrac{69}{5}},\tfrac{\sqrt{641}}{5}\right)\\
\\
\end{split} \\  
\hline  
\begin{split}   
\begin{split}   
\left(x,y,z\right)\quad\\
\in{\mathbb{Q}_+}\!\!^3\setminus{\mathbb{Z}_+}\!\!^3
\end{split}
\end{split}&   
\begin{split}
\\
\left(\tfrac{2}{3},\tfrac{23}{3},\tfrac{50}{3}\right)\,\left(\tfrac{13}{3},\tfrac{14}{3},\tfrac{34}{3}\right)\,\left(\tfrac{11}{3},\tfrac{16}{3},\tfrac{37}{3}\right)\\
\\
\end{split} 
&   
\begin{split}
\\
\left(\tfrac{18}{7},\tfrac{67}{7},\tfrac{130}{7}\right)\,\left(\tfrac{46}{7},\tfrac{53}{7},\tfrac{94}{7}\right)\,\left(\tfrac{\sqrt{1801}}{7},\tfrac{4\sqrt{211}}{7},\tfrac{3\sqrt{1121}}{7}\right)\\
\\
\end{split} \\  
\hline   
\begin{split}   
\begin{split}   
\left(\sqrt{x},\sqrt{y},\sqrt{z}\right)\\
\in{\mathbb{Q}_+}\!\!^3\setminus{\mathbb{Z}_+}\!\!^3\,\,
\end{split}
\end{split}&   
\begin{split}
\\
\left(\tfrac{25}{9},\tfrac{64}{9},\tfrac{196}{9}\right)\,\left(\tfrac{58}{9},\tfrac{74}{9},\tfrac{113}{9}\right)\,\left(\tfrac{49}{9},\tfrac{83}{9},\tfrac{122}{9}\right)\\
\\
\end{split} 
&   
\begin{split}
\\
\left(?,?,?\right)\,\left(?,?,?\right)\,\left(?,?,?\right)\\
\\
\end{split} \\    
\hline   
\end{array} 
} 
\end{align*}

According to **individ**, the solution of Diophantine system can be given by it

\begin{align*}
\left\{
\begin{split}
x&=\left(\frac{1}{u}-\frac{u}{2}+v\right)^2-uv\\
y&=\frac{2}{u}\left(\frac{2}{u}-\frac{u}{2}\right)\\
z&=\left(\frac{1}{u}-\frac{u}{2}-v\right)^2+uv\\
a&=\frac{2}{u}\left(\frac{1}{u}-\frac{u}{2}-v\right)\\
b&=\left(\frac{1}{u}-\frac{u}{2}-v\right)^2+2uv+\frac{u^2}{2}\\
c&=\frac{2}{u}\left(\frac{1}{u}-\frac{u}{2}+v\right)\\
d&=\frac{2}{u}\left(\frac{1}{u}-v\right)\\
e&=\frac{u^2}{4}-\frac{1}{u^2}+v^2\\
f&=\frac{2}{u}\left(\frac{1}{u}+v\right)
\end{split}
\right.\qquad\quad(1)
\end{align*}

**But how to find out the result in another situation?**

Square Eulerian Quadruples:
https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0609127.pdf

System of Diophantine equations (a):
https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1682351p10728828

Comment: Through simplification, the unknowns are separated. But it's still hard.
\begin{cases}
a^2 b^2 - c^2 + (1 - a^4 - b^4) x + (a^2 b^2 + 2 c^2) x^2 - 2 x^3 - c^2 x^4 + x^5=0\\
a^2 c^2 - b^2 + (1 - a^4 - c^4) y + (a^2 c^2 + 2 b^2) y^2 - 2 y^3 - b^2 y^4 + y^5=0\\
b^2 c^2 - a^2 + (1 - b^4 - c^4) z + (b^2 c^2 + 2 a^2) z^2 - 2 z^3 - a^2 z^4 + z^5=0
\end{cases}